# Why does OkHttpClient connect to local host 127.0.0.1:28080

Tags: java, android

I want to use OkHttpClient to connect a server like this :

why does it connect to 127.0.0.1?

```
fun connectUrl(serverAddress: String): Boolean{
        return try {
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder().url(serverAddress).build()
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            LogUtils.showLog(TAG,"$serverAddress, connectUrl success,${response.code()} ${response.body().string()}")
            true
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            LogUtils.showLog(TAG,"$serverAddress, connectUrl fail")
            e.printStackTrace()
            false
        }

    }
```

but this function throws an Exception:

```
I/EpgClient(16422):  http://otta.bbtv.cn/tv, connectUrl fail
W/System.err(16422): java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:28080
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:189)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:173)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
W/System.err(16422):    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
```

Comment: does your device have a proxy configured or something like that?

Comment: There's a 302 jump on the server.

Comment: 1. Paste your serverAddress; 2.Visit your serverAddress in your browser and  see what happened.